# How to Group undead mobs in a datapack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I have this in my datapack, in a JSON file:

```
{
  "values": [
    "minecraft:drowned",
    "minecraft:husk",
    "minecraft:phantom",
    "minecraft:skeleton",
    "minecraft:skeleton_horse",
    "minecraft:stray",
    "minecraft:wither",
    "minecraft:wither_skeleton",
    "minecraft:zoglin",
    "minecraft:zombie",
    "minecraft:zombie_horse",
    "minecraft:zombie_villager",
    "minecraft:zombified_piglin"
  ]
}
```

The path to the file is namespace/tags/entity_types/undead.json

But when I try this:

```
execute at @s run effect give @e[distance=0.5..4,type=undead] instant_health 1 1
```

it won't work.

Will anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a hashtag:

```
execute at @s run effect give @e[distance=0.5..4,type=#undead] instant_health 1 1
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, it might need a namespace, like: `type=#namespace:undead`